# How can I get this C program to accept new input without adding it to the old input?

Tags: c

I'm stuck on a programming exercise I have to do for homework. I've gotten so close to completing it, but I just can't figure out how to have the program ask the user to "Enter next set of limits" at the end without the program adding the new input to the old input.

Here's the question exactly as it appears in my book:

> Write a program that requests lower and upper integer limits, calculates the sum of all the integer squares from the square of the lower limit to the square of the upper limit, and displays the answer. The program should then continue to prompt for limits and display the answers until the user enters an upper limit that is equal to or less than the lower limit. A sample run should look something like this:
>
> ```
> Enter lower and upper integer limits: 5 9
> The sums of the squares from 25 to 81 is 255
> Enter next set of limits: 3 25
> The sums of the squares from 9 to 625 is 5520
> Enter next set of limits: 5 5
> Done
> ```

Here's the code I've written:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int index, lower, upper, square, total, input;

    printf("Enter lower and upper integer limits: ");

    for (input = scanf("%d %d", &lower, &upper); input == 2; printf("Enter the next set of limits: \n"), scanf("%d %d", &lower, &upper))
    {
        for (index = lower; index <= upper; index++)
        {
            square = index * index;
            total += square;
        }
        printf("The sums of the squares from %d to %d is %d\n", lower * lower, upper * upper, total);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I've been working on this for over an hour.

Update, here's what I have now, but it's still not right since it doesn't print out "done" when the upper and lower limits are the same:

## include

int main(void)
{
    int index, lower, upper, square, total;

```
printf("Enter lower and upper integer limits: ");

while (scanf("%d %d", &lower, &upper) == 2)
{
    total = 0;
    for (index = lower; upper > index; index++)
    {
        square = index * index;
        total += square;
    }
    printf("The sums of the squares from %d to %d is %d\n", lower * lower, upper * upper, total);
    printf("Enter the next set of limits: \n");
}


return 0;
```

}

*UPDATE************

Thanks to everyone's help I think I finally got it:

## include

int main(void)
{
    int index, lower, upper, square, total;

```
printf("Enter lower and upper integer limits: ");



while (scanf("%d %d", &lower, &upper) == 2)
{
    while (lower < upper)
    {
    total = 0;
    for (index = lower; index <= upper; index++)
    {
        square = index * index;
        total += square;
    }
        printf("The sums of the squares from %d to %d is %d\n", lower * lower, upper * upper, total);
        printf("Enter the next set of limits: \n");
        scanf("%d %d", &lower, &upper);

}
    printf("Done");
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Hint: I can't see any test for 'upper' greater than 'lower' in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the code in :

```
while( upper > lower ) { 
...
}
```

(And initialize `upper` and `lower` appropriately so the loop is entered.)

Comment: Hi William. I'm not sure how this helps... I initialized total to zero like paddy suggested, and that took care of the problem of the problem where the program would add the new input to the old input, however I still can't figure out to make it read "done" when the user enters an upper and lower limit that is the name number...

Answer (score 1):

I really hate your `for` loop.  But that's an aside.

Just set `total` to zero inside the loop...  You should do that anyway.  At the moment it's uninitialised.

You should exit the loop when `lower == upper` without doing the calculation.  See previous note on my thoughts about your `for` loop.

Maybe something like this:

```
printf("Enter lower and upper integer limits: ");
fflush(stdout);

while ( 2 == scanf("%d %d", &lower, &upper) && lower < upper )
{
    total = 0;

    // Do calculation and output result...

    printf("Enter the next set of limits: ");
    fflush(stdout);
}

printf("Done\n");
```

Comment: Paddy, thanks for your help. Do you know of another way to do the loop without using fflush(stdout) because I haven't learned about that yet, not have I learned the && notation.

Comment: Here's what I've got now. I think it looks better, but I still can't figure out to get the program to terminate and say "Done" when the upper and lower input are the same.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int index, lower, upper, square, total;
    
    
    printf("Enter lower and upper integer limits: ");
    
    while (scanf("%d %d", &lower, &upper) == 2)
    {
        total = 0;
        for (index = lower; upper > index; index++)
        {
            square = index * index;
            total += square;
        }
        printf("The sums of the squares from %d to %d is %d\n", lower * lower, upper * upper, total);
        printf("Enter the next set of limits: \n");
    }
         
    
    return 0;
}

Comment: You don't have to flush.  It's just that you might not see the output if your terminal is line-buffered.  As for the operator `&&`, well, now you know.  Don't go being ignorant of basic language constructs just because you haven't covered them in your class.  Presumably you have a text book for the course, and presumably you have been reading it.

Comment: paddy, i've been reading it, but i would think that the book wants to solve this problem without using tools that i will learn about in later chapters.

Comment: So in that code you posted as a comment, at the top of the loop you could write `if( lower >= upper) break;`.  But you're going to tell me you haven't learned about `break`.  So you'll have to settle for some code repetition.  Read the other answer and do your `scanf` in two places (one above the loop) and one inside the loop.  Then don't do the calculation if the values are not in the correct range.  Lots of repetition.

Comment: Thanks, paddy. I'm looking forward to learning these other tools you are mentioning so I don't have to do so much repetition.

Answer (score 1):

```
int index, lower, upper, square, total, input;
while(1)
{
    total = 0;
    printf("Enter lower and upper integer limits: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    input = scanf("%d %d", &lower, &upper); 
    if(input != 2) continue;
    if(upper <= lower) break;
    for (index = lower; index <= upper; index++)
    {
        square = index * index;
        total += square;
    }
    printf("The sums of the squares from %d to %d is %d\n", lower , upper, total );
}
printf("Done\n");
```

Comment: But shouldn't "if(input != 2) continue;" be "if(input == 2) continue;"?

Comment: continue means start the next loop iteration. We expect 2 input items. In this case we should still be in the loop. Any other value is an error and we want to ask for our inputs again.